# Test connection failed because of an error in initializing provider (instant client)

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g, odbc, instantclient

I am Getting this error message:

> Test connection failed because of an error in initializing provider.
>   Oracle client and networking components were not found. These
>   components are supplied by Oracle Corporation and are part of the
>   Oracle Version 7.3.3 or later client software installation. Provider
>   is unable to function until these components are installed

I want to connection a application to oracle database this application will print identification card for a particular person

I have `instant_client_10_2` on C drive and added the 
path to `=> C:\instant_client_10_2;`

Created a `TNS_ADMIN` and set the path there `=> C:\instant_client_10_2;` but still i have this error message popping up while connecting the software to the Database.

While connecting the ODBC in the computer is works and the test connection is successful.

I am using 64-bit OS, and the instant client is also 64-bit

Comment: What exactly is generating that message - how is it being tested? How is the software connecting to the database? Is it linked to (and can see) the instant client libraries?

Comment: The ID Card Software is generating that error message while testing the connection .  it is been test using the test connection feature in the software . software is connecting to the oracle db  yes the PC is linked to the db it has all the file which is in instantclient_12_1 on the oracle website..additional file which is tnsname.ora

Comment: Presumably it's expecting you to have the full client and to be able to locate it through the registry, which isn't the case with instant client. You might be able to tell it where to look, but without knowing what the software is I can't guess how. Maybe you should ask the software provider if they support instant client, and if so how to configure it. Or maybe the software is 32-bit and just needs the 32-bit client - the OS being 64-bit doesn't matter if the software is 32-bit.

Comment: the software name is IDCentre Identification Software

Comment: Problem Solved , installed Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2
Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x86)
Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x64)